# Rails / Active Record find with join, limit and offset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, deprecated

I've put together the following query, which works as I expect it to:

```
  stuff = @thing.children.find(
    :all,
    :joins => :other,
    :conditions => {:others => {:another_id => some_id}},
    :limit => my_limit,
    :offset => my_offset,
  )
```

However, queries of the form `find(:all)` are deprecated. I have tried changing my query to the following form:

```
  stuff = @thing.children.find(
    :joins => :other,
    :conditions => {:others => {:another_id => some_id}},
    :limit => my_limit,
    :offset => my_offset,
  ).all
```

but this throws a database error. What's the correct way to write this query?

Comment: I think u should use AREL, u can easiely consruct same query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of rewriting it to Arel, you can simply, change the .find to .all, and remove the :all symbol like so:

```
stuff = @thing.children.all(
  :joins => :other,
  :conditions => {:others => {:another_id => some_id}},
  :limit => my_limit,
  :offset => my_offset,
)
```